# NOT NULL constraint failed: users_usermodel.password

Tags: python, django

I have created a Custom User Model(I am new to this Curtom thing) And I got this error at login. NOT NULL constraint failed: users_usermodel.password. I don't understand what to do. Here is my models.py and views.py

I changes the login to mylogin because I thought the function might contrdict the django login funtion. but nothing changed. Please help me solve my problem

Models.py

```
# Custom User Model Code
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)


class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email,first_name, last_name, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, favorite color
         and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email,first_name, last_name,  password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class UserModel(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name','last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from .models import UserModel

# Create your views here.
def profile(request):
    return render(request, '/users/profile.html')

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_name = request.POST.get('firstname')
        last_name = request.POST.get('lastname')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password1 = request.POST.get('password1')
        password2 = request.POST.get('password2')

        if password1 == password2:
            user = UserModel(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email, password=password1)
            user.save()
            return render(request, 'users/login.html')
            
        else:
            message = 'Invalid Credentials'
            return redirect('users/register.html', {'message':message})

    return render(request,'users/register.html')
    
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password') 
        print(password)  
        
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(email=email)
            if password == user.password:
               return redirect(request, 'themes/index.html')
            else:
                message = 'Invali Credentials'
                return render(request,'users/login.html', {'message':message})

        except:
            message = 'Invalid Credentials'
            return render(request,'users/login.html', {'message':message})
    return render(request,'users/login.html')

def userlogout(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('home')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your manager,you have password set as None,that's y it's throwing this error,just set your function like the following `_create_user(self,email,first_name,last_name,password):`
this should fix your problem,and also don't forget to setup AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings.

Comment: Ok, But now it says IntegrityError at /users/register
UNIQUE constraint failed: users_usermodel.email

Comment: When you tried to create users before,they were being created but an issue was caused after creation when you set the password,if u look into your database you'll find the users created,if you remove those users or try to add with another email it should work I believe.